# innertext in simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, web-crawler

[Why do inner text is not active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFlXz.png)

[Here is HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g1i6.png)

[Here is HTML code]

```
<ul class="product">
<li class="product col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 "><div class="product-header">
<a href="/so-mi-octopus-xanh-soc-trang-p5163098.html">
<img src="//cdn.nhanh.vn/cdn/store/17863/ps/20170925/0ctopus_thumb_450x600.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image">
</a><div class="buttons">
<a href="/so-mi-octopus-xanh-soc-trang-p5163098.html" rel="nofollow" class="button add_to_cart_button">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Thêm vào giỏ</span></a>
<a data-product_id="5163098" class="button btnFav" rel="nofollow">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Yêu thích</span>
</a></div></div><h3><a href="/so-mi-octopus-xanh-soc-trang-p5163098.html">Sơ mi Octopus xanh sọc trắng</a></h3><span class="price">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
400,000 ₫                            </span>
</span></li>
</ul>
```

[Here is my code]

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";
$html=file_get_html("http://zuhaus.vn/zu-design-pc150502.html?page=1");
$ds=$html->find("ul.products li");
foreach ($ds as $sp) {
    # code...
    $price=$sp->find("span.price span",0);
    echo $price;
    $name=$sp->find("h3 a",1)->innertext;
    echo $name;
}
?>
```

I have tried a lot of test case but it wont work :"<
Thanks you
P/s I used library simple_html_dom

Comment: Please put code in the question, not at external sites.  Users on StackOverflow will help you, **after you help yourself**.  Take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  Do some research: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527.
Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the contents of a tag and included in h3 then you have a syntax error in the line

```
$name = $sp->find("h3 a", 1)->innertext;
```

I suggest checking the syntax for the following

```
$name = $sp->find('h3', 1)->find('a', 1)->innertext;
```

Comment: If my answer helped solve the problem please repay the points

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with your selector, i changed the selector for the product name, and it just worked, also use curl to improve the fast of crawling

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";



$ch = curl_init("http://zuhaus.vn/zu-design-pc150502.html?page=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page);

$ds=$html->find("ul.products li");
foreach ($ds as $sp) {
    # code...
    $price=$sp->find("span.price span",0);
    echo $price;
    $name=$sp->find("a",3)->innertext; // this is where the problem on your code
    echo $name;

echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: $name=$sp->find("h3 a",1)->innertext;
echo $name;  the same as my code now but it wont work . Thank you at all ^^

Comment: can you please paste your tried code here in stackoverflow.?

Comment: I have reedited my code. This is my first time I have posted question here ^^ :"<